# How to use the wait and notify methods correctly?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, async-await, threadpool

I have a problem with the asynchronous call.
I need my "do" loop to wait for the asynchronous call to continue.
But when you run the method "lock.wait ()" the application frozen and asynchronous call is not cales.

```
lock.wait();
```

the application frozen, but the command line below is not called and the application does not proceed to the method below:

```
callUser.enqueue(new Callback<BaseResponse<User>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<BaseResponse<User>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        updateUsersFromServer(response.body());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                null, 500, R.string.order_unavailable);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
    }
});
```

I need to understand better what the "wait ()" methods are like.

How do I make the application not stop in the "wait ()" method?

```
public void fetchUser(Integer cdCode, String pinckingListNumber) {
    List<User> Users = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        fetchUserApi(cdCode, pinckingListNumber);
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                callUser = false;
                UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                        null, 500, R.string.order_unavailable);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
            }
        }
        offset = offset + 10;
        if (!ObjectValidation.isEmptyOrNull(response)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.getRecords().size(); i++) {
                Users.add(response.getRecords().get(i));
            }
            if (response.getMeta().getRecordCount() < response.getMeta().getOffset())
                callUser = false;
        } else {
            callUser = false;
            UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                    null, 500, R.string.order_unavailable);
            EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            callUser = false;
            UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                    null, 500, R.string.order_unavailable);
            EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
        }
    } while (callUser);

    UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
            Users, 200, R.string.delivery_success);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
}

private void fetchUserApi(Integer cdCode, String pinckingListNumber) {
    UserResource UserResource = getRetrofit().create(UserResource.class);
    Call<BaseResponse<User>> callUser = UserResource.getListUsers(
            authController.getTokenHeader(),
            pinckingListNumber,
            cdCode,
            limit,
            offset
    );

    callUser.enqueue(new Callback<BaseResponse<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<BaseResponse<User>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            updateUsersFromServer(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                    null, 500, R.string.order_unavailable);
            EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
        }
    });
}

private void updateUsersFromServer(BaseResponse<User> baseResponseUsers) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        response = baseResponseUsers;
        lock.notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually asking here?  The literal answer to the only discernable question is "lots of people do".  If you want help, you need to ask a clear and definite question.  Not "please help me" or "please explain it to me" ... neither of which are questions that we can answer.

Comment: If you can't ask a clear / definite question, my best advice would be to look for more example, tutorials, books ... and read / reread them until you do understand.  Alternatively, find an expert who is prepared to give you some one-to-one tutoring on the subject.  Hint: StackOverflow is NOT the place to find such a person.  Try your local university ...

Comment: Soo why are you writing wait method?

Comment: Sorry for the poorly crafted question, I've tried it better now. I have difficulty writing in English, I would like a little patience with me.

Comment: I edited the title of your qestion because "who" <=> "which person", and I think you wanted to say "how to ..." <=> "what should one do to ...".

Comment: Define 'application crashed'. What happened? Thread blocked? GUI froze? Unexpecgted execution path? Exception? Exit with core dump? Computer exploded?

Comment: I thank you so much for helping me, I really have to use the translate for the sentences I create. I tried to improve the question again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the case of the application I can not use the Retrofit asynchronous method.
I do not know is some retrofit bug, but when I was using the retrofit asynchronous method and executed the Wait () command the application froze.

So I had to create the synchronization method of the retrofit and then use a Thread, so that I could use the wait and notify methods without the application freezing.

```
public void fetchUser(Integer cdCode, String pinckingListNumber) {
     List<User> Users = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            fetchUserApi(cdCode, pinckingListNumber);
            // My code modification
            synchronized (thread) {
                try {
                    thread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    callUser = false;
                    UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                            null, 500, R.string.order_unavailable);
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
                }
            }
            offset = offset + 10;
            if (!ObjectValidation.isEmptyOrNull(response)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.getRecords().size(); i++) {
                    Users.add(response.getRecords().get(i));
                }
                if (response.getMeta().getRecordCount() < response.getMeta().getOffset())
                    callUser = false;
            } else {
                callUser = false;
                UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                        null, 500, R.string.order_unavailable);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                callUser = false;
                UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                        null, 500, R.string.order_unavailable);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
            }
        } while (callUser);

        UserEvent UserEvent = new UserEvent(
                Users, 200, R.string.delivery_success);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent);
    }

    private void fetchUserApi(Integer cdCode, String pinckingListNumber) {
        UserResource userResource = getRetrofit().create(UserResource.class);
        final Call<BaseResponse<User>> callUserAPI = userResource.getListUsers(
                    authController.getTokenHeader(),
                    pinckingListNumber,
                    cdCode,
                    limit,
                    offset
            );
            // My code modification
            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        updateUsersFromServer(callUserAPI.execute().body());
                        synchronized (thread) {
                            thread.notify();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();
    }
    private void updateUsersFromServer(BaseResponse<User> baseResponseUsers) {
            response = baseResponseUsers;
        }
```

Comment: The difference being? The bug having been? the cure being? Mere code is not an answer. You have to explain.

Comment: I edited the post for an explanation. Please do not understand, leave your comment below